# Android Activity Context NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, android-context

I'm having some strange errors reports on Google Play Developer Console regarding NPEs on Activity context or Application context. I can't recreate this error on my device and I know it's working fine on most devices.

This is my Main Activity, the one that is first opened on app startup:

```
public class ActSplash extends Activity {
  private Sync sync;
  private Context ctx;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.act_splash);

  do {
      ctx = this.getApplicationContext(); //Using just "this" doesn't work either.
  } while (ctx==null);

  sync = Sync.getInstance(ctx); //Apparently ctx is null at this point in some devices
}
```

This is my Sync class (Singleton)

```
public class Sync {
   private Context ctx;
   private static Sync INSTANCE = null;

   public static Sync getInstance(Context ctx) {
      if (INSTANCE == null) createInstance(ctx);
      return INSTANCE;
   }

   private synchronized static void createInstance(Context ctx) {
      if (INSTANCE == null) { 
        INSTANCE = new Sync(ctx);
      }
   }

   private Sync(Context _ctx)
   {
      ctx = _ctx;
      //NPE on following line
      WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      ...
   }
```

This is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.ActSplash}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.xxx.xxx.Sync.<init>(SourceFile:82)
at com.xxx.xxx.Sync.void createInstance(android.content.Context)(SourceFile:67)
at com.xxx.xxx.Sync.com.xxx.xxx.Sync getInstance(android.content.Context)(SourceFile:72)
at com.xxx.xxx.ActSplash.void onCreate(android.os.Bundle)(SourceFile:40)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5058)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
... 11 more
```

What can I do to make sure I have `ctx!=null` before calling:

```
sync = Util_Sync.getInstance(ctx);
```

Comment: What does "using `this` doesn't work" mean? What happens?

Comment: It means that if I do: ctx = this; I still get NPE error on sync = Util_Sync.getInstance(ctx);

Comment: Please post the stack trace, as your interpretation seems unlikely. Also, get rid of that endless loop -- not only can `getApplicationContext()` not be `null` there, but blocking the main application thread until the battery runs out of the device is not going to help any.

Comment: I've updated the question including the stack trace.

Comment: @AndresY. Since `this` can never be null, there is something else causing the NPE.

Comment: What is line 82 of SourceFile?

Comment: Further to your Sync code being posted `private Context ctx;`

is never used, so remove it.

Comment: @Code-Guru It just ocurred to me that, since this is happening only on some devices, the problem may not be a null context but some problem with the WifiManager. Is it possible that some devices get the NPE here because it has no wifi or wifi is turn off or something else related to wifi?

Comment: @AndresY. I suggest that you use a debugger to find out exactly which reference is null. It still seems like the NPE is caused by code which you are not showing here.

Comment: @AndresY. Welcome to S.O. I recommend you read the tour and help, upvote and mark answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

so as you have code that does not change

```
do {
  ctx = this.getApplicationContext(); //Using just "this" doesn't work either.
} while (ctx==null);
```

this is going to result in an endless loop, if it fails to get `ctx`.

Activity is a context!  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

> Known Indirect Subclasses
>   AbstractInputMethodService, AccessibilityService, AccountAuthenticatorActivity, ActionBarActivity, **Activity**, ActivityGroup, AliasActivity, Application, BackupAgent, BackupAgentHelper, ContextThemeWrapper, and 23 others.

Try

```
ctx = this;
```

**Update**

Further to your Sync code being posted

```
private Context ctx;
```

is never used, so remove it.

Comment: The cast isn't even required.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `this` can never be `null`. Assume to the contrary that it can be, then this means you would have a call such as `myObj.myMethod()` where `myObj` is `null`. But then this method call would throw a NPE before execution enters `myMethod()`.

This means that your error is coming from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind posting the full constructor ? null pointer exception occurs somewhere inside of `Sync()` constructor. `_ctx` is not null though